# Will communication happens with different subnets

Tags: networking, subnet

If I have two IP's
192.168.0.12 /24
192.168.0.13 /28  , Will they communicate even if they are in different subnet?

I know that PC will do AND operation to know whether the destination is in same network or not if I do Im getting that both belongs to same network and
the subnet range of /24 is 192.168.0.0      192.168.0.255
the subnet range of /28 is 192.168.0.0  -   192.168.0.15
question is the range 0-15(/28) comes under 0-255(/24) and if i do AND operation it looks like this

```
192.168.0.12 /24
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.255

10000000.12345678.0000000.00001100  192.168.0.12    
11111111.11111111.1111111.00000000  255.255.255.0
10000000.12345678.0000000.00000000  AND operation



192.168.0.13 /28
192.168.0.0 -   192.168.0.15

10000000.12345678.0000000.00001101  192.168.0.13
11111111.11111111.1111111.11110000  255.255.255.240
10000000.12345678.0000000.00000000  And Operation
```

And operation is same so will they communicate

Comment: Your question is unclear. For two hosts to be in the same subnet, their subnet masks must match **exactly**. "Overlapping" masks don't make it possible for hosts to communicate; at best one host would be able to send packets to the other, but the opposite would not be true.

Answer (score 1):

First, this isn't a good idea.  You are likely to experience very strange problems that you don't know how to fix.

Second, these two subnets are not "different" except in a strict sense; they are overlapping.

It would be more accurate to say that both IP addresses are in both overlapping network definitions.

- 192.168.0.1/24: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255
- 192.168.0.1/28: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.15

They are probably able to communicate directly with each other, yes.  But, and this is an important question: Why?